# How can I define my association correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

Why does this code return an error?
Is it because my association from `Community` or `CommunityTopics` are not set up correctly?

> undefined method `user_profile' for nil:NilClass

```
  <% @community.community_topics.each do |topic| %>
    <li>
    <%= link_to topic.user.user_profile.nickname, community_topic_path(@community, topic) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
```

I have 4 models such as

1. User
2. UserProfile (This is always set with User one to one)
3. Community
4. CommunityTopic

   - Users can create Community as much as they want.
   - Users can post Topics to any Community as much as they want.

In this case how the association should be like?
Is my statement fine??

**User**

```
has_one :user_profile
has_many :communities
has_many :community_topics
```

**UserProfile**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**Community**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :community_topics
```

**CommunityTopics**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :community
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like a problem with your associations, `topic.user` is nil for at least one of the topics. If `CommunityTopic` should always have a `user` you'll need to implement a validation (and NOT NULL database constraint) to ensure the presence of the user association on that class and clean up any existing data. Otherwise you will need to code defensively, e.g.:

```
<%= link_to topic.user.user_profile.nickname, community_topic_path(@community, topic) if topic.user %>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! You are right!! I had some records with nil user_id:( I feel so stupid:( Thanks anyways!